# call wicket from the element that is not wicket-component

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, wicket

I'm using js-lib for transform  to rich-editor (with option "bold", "italic" and others).

RichEditor contains button UploadImage, and I can change call-back of this button:

```
function startUploadingImage(field_name, url, type, win) {
    //
}
```

I have created modal window for selecting file.
So, how I can call wicket from function "startUploadingImage"??

I tried something like this:

---

```
// Java-script:
function startUploadingImage(field_name, url, type, win) {
    wicketAjaxGet('..?1-1.IBehaviorListener.0-&action=uploadImage');
}
```

---

```
// and Wicket (class extends WebPage):

clickBehavior = new AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior() {
    @Override
    protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        IRequestParameters requestParameters = getRequestCycle().getRequest().getRequestParameters();
        String action = requestParameters.getParameterValue("action").toString();
        if (action.equals("uploadImage"))
            modal1.show(target);
    }
};
add(clickBehavior);
```

---

But this does not work. 
I'm begginer in wicket so not beat much.

Comment: Just as an aside: Why are you not using Wicket components to do this?

Comment: My task is to tie logic to the button editor. I would gladly do it with wicket-components and not racked my brain =)

Comment: Well if you are looking to have a file input field, wicket certainly has a component that does that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior url to the javascript so it can be called. A neat way i do this, is to add a new data tag to the html of the component you add the AjaxBehavior to. You can do this by overriding the onComponentTag method of the AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior .

```
@Override
protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) 
{       
    tag.put("callback-url", behavior.getCallbackUrl());     
    super.onComponentTag(tag);
}
```

Now in the javascript all you have to do is find the callback-url tag and get its value, this will give you the url to call.

```
wicketAjaxGet($element.attr('callback-url'), function() { }, function() { });
```